# Find minimal spanning tree of graph with edge values from 1 to 5 integers

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

How can I find the minimal spanning tree of graph with edge values from 1 to 5 integers (no need to be unique) most effectively? I know I can use Kruskal algorithm, but how can I modify the algorithm to find it faster when I know there are edges with values only 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5? I cant figure it out how it could be faster when I know this limitation on edges.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140344/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67432796/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [complexity of Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Complexity). Since the edges are with integer weights, you can sort them in linear time. The entire algorithm will take a total of $O(|V|\alpha(|E|)+|E|)$. We need $O(|E|)$ to sort, and an additional $O(|V|\alpha(|E|))$ for Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: so what is the modification? how can I fasten it when I know the values are 1-5 in comparison to e.g. graph with values 1-5000?

Comment: Read the last paragraph in the link. It explains what needs to be done and what the complexity will be